# Linq to XML how many times is this XML file getting read?

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-xml

My site navigation has a concept of categories that have a description, image, and pages associated with them.

In _ViewStart.cshtml I have the following LINQ query and then store the results in PageData because I might be using the categories more than once on a given page and didn't want to re-run the query.

```
XDocument navigation = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Navigation.xml"));
IEnumerable<Category> categories = from category in navigation.Root.Descendants("category")
                                   select new Category(
                                        category.Attribute("name").Value,
                                        category.Element("description").Value,
                                        new CategoryImage(
                                            category.Element("image").Element("path").Value,
                                            category.Element("image").Element("cssClass").Value,
                                            category.Element("image").Element("description").Value
                                        ),
                                        (from page in category.Descendants("page") select new BetterSolutions.ViewModels.ProductPage(page.Attribute("display").Value, page.Value)).ToList()
                                   );
PageData["categories"] = categories;
```

When I watch what happens through the debugger, anytime I access PageData["categories"] it keeps going back to the query in _ViewStart.cshtml.

When I change the above code by adding parenthesis around the LINQ query and adding .ToList() at the end, it appears to execute once and then never again.

What is the way I should be doing this? I think that adding the .ToList() is correct since the query appears to be only running once, but I might be misunderstanding how deferred execution within LINQ to XML is actually working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the way I should be doing this? I think that adding the .ToList() is correct since the query appears to be only running once, but I might be misunderstanding how deferred executing within LINQ to XML is actually working.

What you see **is** deferred execution. When you create your `categories` it's not a collection of items: it's just a query which will be executed when results are needed. And that query definition is stored in `PageData["categories"]`. So every time to take it from there you have to execute it to get results.

Adding `ToList()` makes the results necessary right away, because you ask for list of results. And after that that list is stored in `PageData["categories"]`. That's why you don't have to execute query over and over again: because you already have the results stored in a list, and you don't even know where results came from before.

**What is the right way to go?** It depends. If you expect the file to change between `PageData["categories"]` calls and you need it to always return accurate results, you may stay with your current solution. If file does not change or it's OK not to read the file just once and discard all changes made to the file during program execution you should use `ToList()` to make it performing better and avoid unnecessary file access.

***Update***

My main answer is not completely correct. Even without `ToList()` accessing `PageData["categories"]` would not make the file access again, because the file is already completely loaded and parsed into `XDocument` instance. But it would travers the document itself to execute the query.

Comment: That makes sense. When I create categories does C# know that the results of the query are going to be IEnumerable<Category>?  Otherwise, shouldn't I be getting an error on compile?

Comment: Yes, the query is typed to return collection of `Category` items.

Answer (score 0):

it Looks like you forgot to put to ToList() call for categories:
the simple fix would be :

```
PageData["categories"] = categories.ToList();
```

Comment: He didn't forget - `What is the way I should be doing this? I think that adding the .ToList() is correct since the query appears to be only running once, but I might be misunderstanding how deferred executing within LINQ to XML is actually working.`